# Can I use multiple "with"?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Just for example:

```
With DependencedIncidents AS
(
    SELECT INC.[RecTime],INC.[SQL] AS [str] FROM
    (
        SELECT A.[RecTime] As [RecTime],X.[SQL] As [SQL] FROM [EventView] AS A 
        CROSS JOIN [Incident] AS X
            WHERE
                patindex('%' + A.[Col] + '%', X.[SQL]) > 0
    ) AS INC
)

With lalala AS
(
    SELECT INC.[RecTime],INC.[SQL] AS [str] FROM
    (
        SELECT A.[RecTime] As [RecTime],X.[SQL] As [SQL] FROM [EventView] AS A 
        CROSS JOIN [Incident] AS X
            WHERE
                patindex('%' + A.[Col] + '%', X.[SQL]) > 0
    ) AS INC
)
```

...doesn't work. "Error near With".

Also, I want to use first with inside second with. Is it real or I need to use temp tables?

Comment: BOL has the exact syntax, too. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx Notice `[ ,...n ]`.

Answer (score 572, accepted):

Try:

```
With DependencedIncidents AS
(
    SELECT INC.[RecTime],INC.[SQL] AS [str] FROM
    (
        SELECT A.[RecTime] As [RecTime],X.[SQL] As [SQL] FROM [EventView] AS A 
        CROSS JOIN [Incident] AS X
            WHERE
                patindex('%' + A.[Col] + '%', X.[SQL]) > 0
    ) AS INC
),
lalala AS
(
    SELECT INC.[RecTime],INC.[SQL] AS [str] FROM
    (
        SELECT A.[RecTime] As [RecTime],X.[SQL] As [SQL] FROM [EventView] AS A 
        CROSS JOIN [Incident] AS X
            WHERE
                patindex('%' + A.[Col] + '%', X.[SQL]) > 0
    ) AS INC
)
```

And yes, you can reference common table expression inside common table expression definition. Even recursively. Which leads to some very [neat tricks](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2010/11/recursive-queries-with-common-table.html).

Comment: For those that didn't immediately notice it like myself, the catch here is adding a comma after the original with statement.. lol

Comment: and not writing the word `with` again

Comment: Hi, is this equivalent to a Cross Join between two tables. Or does this create two separate tables. I wouldn't want to cross join two very large table, is there a way to  efficiently create two separate "with" tables

Comment: @LongLe No, they are not equivalent to joins and they are not tables. These are CTEs - Common Table Expressions. They are more like... named queries that you can use as if they were tables... or rather more like views. Please google them. They are neat. It is one of the best standard SQL features, helping enormously to keep complex queries understandable and under control.

Comment: For those who don't know what 'common table expressions' are, they are 'DependencedIncidents' and 'lalala' in the example given. For detail, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.

Comment: I also think it's good practice to start WITH statement with a semicolon

Answer (score 209):

Yes - just do it this way:

```
WITH DependencedIncidents AS
(
  ....
),  
lalala AS
(
  ....
)
```

You don't need to repeat the `WITH` keyword

Comment: Can lalala use DependencedIncidents?

Comment: Can DependencedIncidents use lalala?

Comment: @HenryYang: no - the later CTE (`lalala`) can use any CTE defined prior to it - but the earlier one cannot use a CTE that is only going to be defined later on....

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by using the temp table,

```
WITH DependencedIncidents AS
(
  ....
)

select * INTO #TempTable from DependencedIncidents 
  
with lalala AS
(
  ....
)

select * from lalala
```

you can also write the second with after the with . You can write a second "with" using ",".

After you finish all of them, you need to run "with" last return value "select * from lalala ".