# Unable to figure out syntax error in my "with"

Tags: sqlite, case

This is my first post. Please excuse any typical noob-mistakes I may have made!
In below code, I am just trying to output two columns "Invoice_id" and "Category".
the second column is being created using case-when condition.
In the case-when condition I am using two tables created using "with" statement.
I am just not able to figure out the syntax error with my "with".
Any help is greatly appreciated!
(I've not adhered to the standard SQL lowercase/uppercase format. Please ignore)

```sql
with get_tracks as
    (
    Select 
        i.invoice_id,
        i.customer_id,
        t.track_id as track_id,
        a.album_id as album_id
    from invoice i
    inner join invoice_line il on i.invoice_id=il.invoice_id
    inner join track t on il.track_id=t.track_id
    inner join album a on a.album_id=t.album_id
    )
with tracks_per_album as
    (
    select 
        count(distinct t.track_id) as num_of_tracks,
        a.album_id as album_id
    from album a 
    inner join track t on a.album_id=t.album_id
    group by 2
    )

select 
    invoice_id,
    case
        when ((select count(distinct track_id) 
        from get_tracks 
        group by album_id
        except
        select num_of_tracks from tracks_per_album
        group by album_id)

        AND

        (select num_of_tracks from tracks_per_album
         group by album_id
         except
         select count(distinct track_id) from get_tracks 
         group by album_id
          ) is Null) then "Album"

          else "Individual"
    end as category
from get_tracks group by 1
```

Error Message:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '
with get_tracks as
    (
    Select 
        i.invoice_id,
        i.customer_id,
        t.track_id as track_id,
        a.album_id as album_id
    from invoice i
    inner join invoice_line il on i.invoice_id=il.invoice_id
    inner join track t on il.track_id=t.track_id
    inner join album a on a.album_id=t.album_id
    )

with tracks_per_album as
    (
    select 
        count(distinct t.track_id) as num_of_tracks,
        a.album_id as album_id
    from album a 
    inner join track t on a.album_id=t.album_id
    group by 2
    )

select 
    invoice_id,
    case
        when ((select count(distinct track_id) 
        from get_tracks 
        group by album_id
        except
        select num_of_tracks from tracks_per_album
        group by album_id)

        AND

        (select num_of_tracks from tracks_per_album
         group by album_id
         except
         select count(distinct track_id) from get_tracks 
         group by album_id
          ) is Null) then "Album"

          else "Individual"
    end as category
from get_tracks group by 1
': near "with": syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of related to [Can I use multiple "with"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375634/can-i-use-multiple-with) since the error is dealing with using Multiple withs. Sorry don't know if this should be a comment or answer but leaving as answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's incorrect syntax. The error message kinda gets lost in the edit:

`from get_tracks group by 1 ': near "with": syntax error`

You only need one `WITH` in this query. To "chain" with statements use this syntax:

```
with get_tracks as
    (
    Select 
     .  
     .  
     .  
     .
    ),

 tracks_per_album as
    (
    select .....
```

Notice the `,` at the end of the first table, and no `with` before creating the second one.